# How to perform this vector/matrix computation?

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, optimal-control, kalman-filter

**Edit**: It seems to me that it could indeed be an outer product. I will keep investigating and update after I reach solid conclusions.

**Background**: I am trying to implement the algorithm explained [here](http://www.koreascience.or.kr/article/ArticleFullRecord.jsp?cn=HSSHBT_2016_v25n3_202) and which consists in, as the title says, *A Two-step Kalman/Complementary Filter for Estimation of Vertical Position Using an IMU-Barometer System*.

At some point in the paper -after equation 3- the author states that (although the paper is in Korean Google Translator does a good job):

*a tilde (~) denotes an outer matrix of the corresponding vector, that is, $\tilde{a}=[a \times]$*

If I am not mistaken this means to calculate the cross product of $a$ and the vector following $a$. As an example, assuming both $a$ and $b$ are vectors, then $\tilde{a}b$ would be $a\times b$. (This interpretation is consistent with equation 3, which updates the representation of the earth frame Z-axis in the sensor coordinate system with the angular velocity measurement of the gyro.)

**Question**: So, if a tilde does in fact mean to calculate the cross product ($\tilde{a}=[a \times]$) how should I perform the following calculation (a simplified version of  equation 6.1 in the paper)?

$$Q=\tilde{Z}\Sigma_G \tilde{Z}$$

where both $Z$ and $\Sigma_G$ are $3\times1$ vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually such tilde notation for a given vector $z=\begin{bmatrix}z_1&z_2&z_3\end{bmatrix}^\top$ means

$$
\tilde{z} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -z_3 & z_2 \\
z_3 & 0 & -z_1 \\
-z_2 & z_1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

however if $\Sigma_G \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times1}$, then the product $\Sigma_G\,\tilde{z}$ has a dimension mismatch (the product $\tilde{z}\,\Sigma_G$ is well defined but is also in $\mathbb{R}^{3\times1}$). But you can also interpret the product as

$$
\tilde{z}\,\Sigma_G\,\tilde{z} = z \times \Sigma_G \times z
$$

which is well defined.

Comment: I will investigate a bit further, test both of your suggestions, and report back. It seems to me that you could be right regarding the meaning of the tilde notation.

Comment: You were right about the tilde notation and its meaning. It is worth pointing out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication